# May I ever catch java.lang.Exception instead of its concrete subclasses?

Tags: exception

May I ever catch java.lang.Exception instead of its subclasses?

Consider this senario:

```
public class Tree {
    public static Tree newInstance() throws NoWaterException, NoSoilException, NoSunshineException {
        ...
        return new Tree();
    }
}
```

When I want to get an instance of Tree, I can do this:

```
public Tree plantTree() throws TreePlantExcetpion {
    try {
        ...
        return Tree.newInstance();
    } catch (NoWaterException e) {
        throw new TreePlantExcetpion("Cannot plant a tree since no water", e);
    } catch (NoSoilException e) {
        throw new TreePlantExcetpion("Cannot plant a tree since no soil", e);
    } catch (NoSunshineException e) {
        throw new TreePlantExcetpion("Cannot plant a tree since no sunshine", e);
    }
}
```

But I can also do this alternatively:

```
public Tree plantTree() throws TreePlantExcetpion {
    try {
        ...
        return Tree.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new TreePlantExcetpion("Cannot plant a tree", e);
    }
}
```

I prefer to the second implementation of method `plantTree`() since it is shorter and clearer, and in this method I don't care about the concrete subclasses of `Exception`, what I need to do is to wrap it in a new  `TreePlantExcetpion` and pass it up. All the detailed information will not be lost. And I am sure that the Tree.newInstance() method will not throw any other type of exceptions (at least for now). May I do it in this way?

**Note**: `NoWaterException`, `NoSoilException`, `NoSunshineException` cannot be subclasses of `TreePlantExcetpion`. They are not in a same inheritance hierarchy.

The point is, if the exception handling is the same for all caught exceptions, may I just catch their super class, i.e. `java.lang.Exception` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `NoWaterException`, `NoSoilException` and `NoSunshineException` subclasses of TreePlantException, and you could just skip the entire try/catch since `TreePlantException` is already declared as thrown.

Comment: what if the classes are not in the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: Then you'd have to catch either the specific exceptions individually , or catch the first common super-class. The problem with the latter approach is if something were to throw a NullPointerException or and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or something similar, as they would get eaten up.